# how to set dynamic icon for android react native firebase through http request

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons, react-native-firebase

Hi I am trying to set custom icon through http request.im using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send api and trying to send notification and I have succeeded but the problem is I can't define custom icon.either it's not showing or it's showing default android icon. Also, it would be great if i can send base64 string as icon. My code is below:

```
{
"to": "dSqZ9U3IA3o:APA91bHR5XRI48k9AUOYR_W3-zxGU1IIffu7amhUtzbaad1ZIoVWrURLDkAZZA49_J_zWKQz7bWbzEckHbOTmonkyNmmRHjxk-mrDw5IDzU9weLF3Wfkghz4RJRQjv8RsSWFUMlHba2w",
  "notification" : {
    "title": "string",
    "body": "string",
    "icon": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-512.png",
    "color": "string",
    "sound": "string",
    "image": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-512.png"
  }
}
```

or

```
"icon":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABEklEQVQ4T43TPyuHURjG8c+vlMUqm2xIkomMhEGieAPCIn8yKZKUyWIhYZBiUCZeALMMShayGWRRilBKp4560nkez1nPub/3ue7ruivKnQa0oQutqEUfXiol6sdRgzf0YAOXv3X/ARZwjVtMYfFvwyLAGjbxhD1M47MsYBRfOMUYbnCVkpv3g31M4Bu7mEl1D8AUoANNOEAjurGdN+wUYBDVOEEn2ssAQkF97DIU9V6gHy04i3f3eUMcQS8e4/C2ou91mMM7mrGKuywkK2EFh3hI6A2pC+k7KrKxCjsIycueIG0Sy2VsDHoHsJ55HGycxUcZQHiTDdE8zmOck07mBWkJz3jFcdHC5QHC9g3HoRYu7A9AKzMRgaU+zgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download png file and place file in android/app/src/main/res/drawable as notification_icon.png

while displaying

```
{
"to": "dSqZ9U3IA3o:APA91bHR5XRI48k9AUOYR_W3-zxGU1IIffu7amhUtzbaad1ZIoVWrURLDkAZZA49_J_zWKQz7bWbzEckHbOTmonkyNmmRHjxk-mrDw5IDzU9weLF3Wfkghz4RJRQjv8RsSWFUMlHba2w",
  "notification" : {
    "title": "string",
    "body": "string",
    "icon": "notification_icon",
    "color": "string",
    "sound": "string",
    "image": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-512.png"
  }
}
```